# Move divs within specific divs and back again at certain breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="result-display">
  <div class="results-heading">
    <div class="heading active" data-tab="first">First</div>
    <div class="heading" data-tab="second">Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="results-body">
    <div class="body-item first current">
      "Text for first item"
    </div>
    <div class="body-item second">
      "Text for second item"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to move `.body-item first` inside of the `.heading` div with the data-tab of `first` and `.body-item second` inside of the `.heading` div with the data-tab of `second` when the window width reaches a certain breakpoint, and back to its original position at another breakpoint ?

Sommething the lines of:

```
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww <= 800) {
        // move inside divs
    } else {
     // move to original positions
    }
  })
```

If so, how could I achieve something like this ?

Comment: Yes it is. What problem are you facing?

Comment: I'm struggling with finding a solution on how to do it.

Comment: Well your code looks fine so far, but there's no attempt to actually move the elements, so I'm not sure what you're struggling with. You just need to use DOM scripting methods to do the actual moving of elements.

Comment: The thing with resize is that it's going to repeat the action so you'll end up getting text repeating as you resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just need [**`appendTo`**](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to add text from source element to target element, in your case

```
$(".body-item.first").appendTo(".heading[data-tab='first']")
```

And same for the other element

```js
$(".body-item.first").appendTo(".heading[data-tab='first']")


$(".body-item.second").appendTo(".heading[data-tab='second']")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-display">
  <div class="results-heading">
    <div class="heading active" data-tab="first">First</div>
    <div class="heading" data-tab="second">Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="results-body">
    <div class="body-item first current">
      "Text for first item"
    </div>
    <div class="body-item second">
      "Text for second item"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont know why I thought it was more complicated than this. Thank you.